# Does Sonarqube supports Xamarin for code quality?

Tags: c#, msbuild, xamarin.ios, sonarqube

I am working on a Xamarin project. I would like to check code quality with sonarqube. I see there is a support for .net/c# project. I have followed the instruction [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) for Xamarin.I was able to do the first two steps  Begin and Rebuild. When i execute the third step "end"

> SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end

I am getting below error

```
mono /Users/apple/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.2.573/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.3.2
Default properties file was found at /Users/apple/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.2.573/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /Users/apple/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.2.573/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
Execution failed. The specified executable does not exist: /Users/apple/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.2.573/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
13:17:17.361  Creating a summary markdown file...
13:17:17.366  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported to use the scanner on non Windows platforms.

There is an open issue for that: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-319

Answer (score 2):

Now SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe has the support for mac, it works.

The sonarqube for MSBuild version 3.0.2 was not supporting Non window OS, now the SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe 4.0 has the support for mac

Also the sonarC# Plugin has to be > 6.6 to run the analysis on mac os version.

Please check the below link,
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111935/source-code-analysis-for-xamarin-project-with-sonarqube-on-mac/p1?new=1